# Variable in Submenu text, GLUT

Tags: opengl, menu, glut, submenu

So, my menu looks like this:

```
typedef struct menuItemStruct {

    char* item;

    char  val;

} menuItemStruct;

static menuItemStruct menu1[] = {
                {"Switch on/off",    '1'},
                {"Accelerate",       '2'},
                {"Decelerate",       '3'},
                {"Widen the arc",    '4'},
                {"Narrow the arc",   '5'}
};

int numItensMenu1 = sizeof( menu1 ) / sizeof( menuItemStruct );
```

And here's my createMenus:

```
void criarMenus( void )
{
    int pend;
    int disp;
    int mainmenu;

    int i;
    int j;

    pend=glutCreateMenu( myMenuEsq );

    for( i=0; i<numItensMenu1; i++ )
    {
        glutAddMenuEntry( menu1[i].item, i );
    }

    disp=glutCreateMenu( myMenuDir );

    for( i=0; i<numItensMenu2; i++ )
    {
        glutAddMenuEntry( menu2[i].item, i );
    }
    mainmenu = glutCreateMenu(myMenuEsq);
    glutAddSubMenu("Pendulum 1", pend);
    glutAddSubMenu("Display", disp);

    glutAttachMenu( GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON );

}
```

[What I achieve is that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egZDt.jpg)

The thing, however, is that the number of pendulums is a variable, from 1 up to 10, so I want my meny to display Pendulum 1, Pendulum 2 etc, and for each of those display a submenu consisting of those that you can see.  I am lost however, when it comes to that line:

```
 glutAddSubMenu("Pendulum 1", pend);
```

Can I replace the "1" with a variable? For example like this:

```
glutAddSubMenu("Pendulum %i", pendulumNumber, pend);
```

Or do I have to do all this manually with ifs? If I can do that, how? Because the above does not work, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

assuming C then you can use snprintf to build the string:

```
char menuName[100];
for(int pendulumNumber=1; pendulumNumber<= 10;pendulumNumber++){
    snprintf(menuName, 100, "Pendulum %i", pendulumNumber);
    glutAddSubMenu(menuName, pend);
}
```

Comment: I can't check it for sure at the moment, because I don't have pendulum placement done yet, but that sounds loike a good idea, didn't think of building a string, I'll follow your advice, thanks.

Comment: Hey, there's this problem though, that even though I add more items in the menu, the submenus still return the same value and I can't assign different actions. Any ideas with that?

Comment: create the submenu in the loop

Comment: How do I assign different values to the menus?